# nodejs fs createWriteStream not working with file path prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, createwritestream

I am trying to call an API, loop through an array of images, assign unique names to each image in the array and then write them to a local directory. If I simplify the code I can write them to the root folder .I already created the sub folder manually, so it existed prior to running the function.

Here is my basic function:

```
const imageFolder = './img';

function downloadImage(url, filepath) {
    client.get(url, res => {
        res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${imageFolder}/${filepath}`));
    });
}

...make api call

const imagesArray = generations.data.map(item => item.generation.image_path);

imagesArray.forEach(item => {
    // const fileName = uuid.v4() + '.webp'; // trying to assign unique filename with uuid
    const fileName = new Date().getTime().toString() + '.webp'; // trying to assign unique filename with date object
    downloadImage(item, fileName);
});
```

If I change

```
res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${imageFolder}/${filepath}`));
```

to

```
res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
```

then it will work but just dumps the images in the root. I was thinking perhaps I was trying to concatenate a variable name with a string (for fileName + '.webp', but it is working in the root as mentioned. See attached image.

I also tried adding the path into the actual function call inside the forEach loop like so

```
downloadImage(item, `${imageFolder}/${fileName}`);
```

I did wonder about needing the `__dirname` variable, or whether it could be a permissions issue, but I don't see any errors.

I am assuming this is pretty straightforward.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OK, was fairly simple and I guess I sort of knew it once I got it working, changing to

```
downloadImage(item, path.join('src', 'img', fileName));
```

[path.join](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/nodejs-file-paths/) concatenates folder names and fixes issues when working across platforms (OSX, Windows etc) which applies in this case as I am testing from both Windows and Mac.